# Using sed awk to replace characters in a string

Tags: html, regex, awk, sed

I have about 300 files in a folder.
I need to search the files for this tag

```
<b>This string must stay</b><br />
```

And replace them with

```
<CustomerInfo>This string must stay</CustomerInfo>
```

The inside string must not be change.

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean, neither what you tried. Look for all files in a specific directory and replace this specific string?

Comment: I have this tag <b>%%%%%</b><br/> need to replace it with <CustomerInfo>%%</CustomerInfo>  regaless of what the content might be

Comment: This is not the way to ask for questions: provide a full example, what you tried and how the output should look like. Also, many edge cases could happen: what if there is other tags within the given text? What if the text jumps to the next line? Clarify this.

Comment: 100% of the files has <b>my string</b><br /> I need to use <b> as start tag and </b><br/> as close tag.. I will replace the start tag as well as the close tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
sed -r 's#<b>([^<]*)</b><br />#<CustomerInfo>\1</CustomerInfo>#g' file
```

Once you are sure it works, replace `-r` for `-ir` to do in place editing.

If you want to run it through your files, as you comment somewhere, do:

```
find $1 -type f -iname '*.html' -exec \ 
       sed -r 's#<b>([^<]*)</b><br />#<CustomerInfo>\1</CustomerInfo>#g' {} \;
```

#### Explanation

- `<b>([^<]*)</b><br />` look for something having `<b>....</b><br />` and catch the text in between.
- `<CustomerInfo>\1</CustomerInfo>` replace it with `<CustomerPage>` + given text + `</CustomerPage>`.

#### Test

Given a sample file:

```
$ cat a
hello
bye
aaa <b>hello</b><br /> beee
<b>hello</b><br />

<b>hello</b>blabla
```

Let's try it:

```
$ sed -r 's#<b>([^<]*)</b><br />#<CustomerInfo>\1</CustomerInfo>#g' a  hello
bye
aaa <CustomerInfo>hello</CustomerInfo> beee
<CustomerInfo>hello</CustomerInfo>

<b>hello</b>blabla
```

Comment: Just 1 more last question.. which command can I use to replace a string like this '(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});' in all the files.. I mean delete all this string representation in all the files

Comment: @KingsleySchmid just use `sed` again:  `sed 's/(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});'//g' file`.

Comment: Be VERY careful. sed cannot operate on strings, only on regexps, and there are several regexp metacharacters in the string you want to search for so they will not match some of the strings you want and falsely match other strings you don't want. You might want to switch to awk since it DOES support search and replace of strings rather than regexps.

Comment: This is completely true, @EdMorton . I guess the only way in `sed` would be to escape any single regex character. It would be very handy if `sed` had an option `-F` like `grep`...

Comment: @fedorqui no, you can't do that because by escaping a regexp character you might be introducing a problem (e.g. what if you escape an escape that was already escaping a different char) and even then you cant deal with the sed regexp delimiters. You just cannot use sed for strings. Period. Yes, a grep-like `-F` for sed would be very useful.

Comment: Hi Fedroqui .. the <CustomerInfo>\1</CustomerIn> did not work.. the original string was not returned.. what I got in the file is just <CustomerInfo>1</CustomerIn> .. the script replaced all the original customer infomation with 1 :-(

Comment: @KingsleySchmid I am very sorry to read this. I think you did not use exactly the command I posted, because I tested it accurately and it works. It is also good to use `sed -i.bak` so that the original file gets backed up as `file.bak`. Take a look, because you may still have the original files somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sed 's@<b>.*</b><br />@<CustomerInfo>This string must stay</CustomerInfo>@g' file.txt
```

Comment: This does not fully address op's question in fact

Comment: Hi Aduch Thanks.. Just forgot that the string inside is not constant.. i.e insome cases.. 'Hallo world' might appear..

Comment: need to do something like  #!/bin/bash  
for file in $(find $1 -type f -iname '*.html'); do  
    replace tags
    
done

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the string in every files in current directory and subdirectories (it will not ignore binary files, so be careful what you wish for)

This works with find in command dependencies (which unix has)

First to be sure this does not break anything try this (it will just show a preview of what it does):

```
find . -type f -exec sed -e 's@<b>\(.*\)</b><br />@<CustomerInfo>\1</CustomerInfo>@g' {} \;
```

If it worked as expected then, here be dragons:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's@<b>\(.*\)</b><br />@<CustomerInfo>\1</CustomerInfo>@g' {} \;
```

Comment: Hi Aduch  .. the <CustomerInfo>\1</CustomerIn> did not work.. the original string was not returned.. what I got in the file is just <CustomerInfo>1</CustomerIn> .. the script replaced all the original customer infomation with 1 :-(

Comment: Did it? I'm really sorry that this happened to you, can you describe your environment (os, version and sed version) ?